# opencv: filter houghlines

Tags: python, opencv

## **BACKGROUND**

Python 2.7
and opencv 2.4

So I'm trying to get hough lines to accurately outline the grid of a chessboard. So far, I've managed to filter a few lines out doing things such as blurring and dilating the image. However, the remaining lines are pretty tricky. Here's an example of the hough lines that I have: [image]

## **QUESTION**

I feel like I'm fairly close to solving this problem but just need a little help to finally get these lines filtered properly. Does anyone have suggestions/code that they can share with me to solve the problem?

Here's the original image for reference:
[image]

Comment: Hope my answer in your old question is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27558127/opencv-find-box-within-a-box/27578622#27578622

Answer (score 0):

There is findChessboardCorners function in OpenCV.
I think it should help to solve your problem.

Comment: that function is used only for calibration really... it's not very effective on a real board with pieces