# Chess pieces position on physical board to a matrix using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, position, chess

Alright, so what I'm trying to do is; using a web camera take a photo and from that photo extract the position of the chess pieces on the board and write them on a matrix, or a list, doesn't matter that much because after that I just need to verify the movement that was done.

I browsed some tutorials and documentation but I'm lost, best lead I could get was by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27558127/opencv-find-box-within-a-box), but I can't even get the grid:
[It can possibly be because of the board itself, or even the fish eye effect of the web camera I'm using has.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMtI6.png)

This is the code in question:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def main():
    im = cv2.imread('opencv_frame_0.png')
    #im = cv2.resize(im, (640, 480))  
    #edge = cv2.imread('edge.png', 0)
    edge = cv2.Canny(im, 60, 160, apertureSize=3)
    lines = cv2.HoughLines(edge, 1, np.pi/180, 100, 100, 50)
    for rho, theta in lines[0]:
        a = np.cos(theta)
        b = np.sin(theta)
        x0 = a*rho
        y0 = b*rho
        x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
        y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
        x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
        y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))
        cv2.line(im, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        # TODO: filter the lines by color and line distance

    cv2.imshow('image', im)
    cv2.imshow('edge', edge)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Anyways, even if I can figure out why `cv2.HoughLines` isn't doing what I want I have no idea how to proceed with the problem, getting the coordinates of the pieces in the board, what spaces are empty and which ones have a piece.

[This is the original image of the ones showed above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6gZx.png)

[A better photo using my smartphone, I put some letters on the pieces thinking it could help in some way, but no new ideas.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXE73.jpg)

Also the matrix I was expecting to get was one like the shown in the [chess python library docs](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
r . b q k b . r
p p p p . Q p p
. . n . . n . .
. . . . p . . .
. . B . P . . .
. . . . . . . .
P P P P . P P P
R N B . K . N R
```

**UPDATE**

Alright, so, using @stateMachine's advice I changed to color detection. What I have now is, using this image: [image: Picture of the board I'm using]

I detect every corner with the help of `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack`, this is the output: [image: Corners of every square.]

Now, what I'm trying to do is getting the coordinates of the middle point of every square on the chessboard. And, because the blue points (showed in the image above) given by cv2 are not in order, I can't directly use 4 of them and just find the middle point, example: `[[254, 606], [387, 465], [519, 187], [314, 262], [172, 132], [315, 329], [179, 405], [523, 395], [246, 334], [112, 475], [519, 256], [383, 327], [382, 193], [392, 534], [596, 531], [461, 601], [238, 130], [175, 198], [452, 327], [458, 533], [525, 461], [181, 471], [40, 339], [594, 460], [381, 260], [175, 336], [43, 477], [448, 191], [454, 394], [173, 264], [518, 118], [521, 323], [245, 262], [387, 396], [245, 404], [251, 540], [42, 408], [182, 543], [36, 204], [45, 614], [590, 322], [453, 258], [45, 545], [456, 466], [307, 125], [109, 338], [600, 597], [321, 537], [592, 392], [111, 545], [106, 203], [392, 603], [107, 266], [242, 198], [38, 269], [446,  53], [585, 185], [588, 253], [114, 610], [531, 599], [99, 65], [108, 407], [309, 55], [377, 54], [33, 135], [380, 122], [30, 67], [530, 530], [449, 123], [169, 64],  [182, 608], [584, 117], [250, 472], [317, 400], [313, 193], [236, 62], [103, 132], [589, 47], [515, 51], [319, 466], [321, 604]]`

So, my current approach is finding the coordinates of the upper left, right and bottom left and right corners, and just divide the distances so I can intersect lines and find more points: [image: 4 exterior corners found.]
[image: Middle points found]

Now, my problem is; if the camera is not facing directly from above, the points in the middle are not really in the middle, the reason is because of the perspective some squares are larger than others, so the division isn't reliable.

What I need to do now is finding 4 points of the list shown above that belong to the same square and with them find the middle point between them, instead of just doing a division that uses the 4 corners of the board.

Code used to find corners (image with just blue dots):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def main():
    frame = cv2.imread("chessboard.jpg")

    cv2.namedWindow("Frame", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

    corners = []

    corners = find_chessboard(frame)

    print(corners)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return True

def find_chessboard(frame):
    img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(img, 81, 0.01, 10)
    corners = np.int0(corners)

    corners_coordinates = [[]]*len(corners)

    i = 0
    for corner in corners:
        x, y = corner.ravel()
        corners_coordinates[i] = [x, y]
        i = i+1

        cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

    return corners_coordinates

if __name__ is "__main__":

    main()
```

Comment: Use `cv2.HoughLinesP` instead of `cv2.HoughLines`

Comment: Do you have to deal with a handmade rickety chessboard like the your image? If so, it cannot be expected that the method which assumes that the grid lines are clean straight lines will work well.

Comment: Why is the image distorted? I'd be smart to undo the fisheye via calibration first, it'll be a lot easier to work with a flat board. Once undistorted, take a picture of the board without any chess pieces on it. Look for the four board corners and fit a rectangle. You know how many squares make up one "board width" you can approximate the location of each square. Then, you may analyze each "square" and detect if a piece is present. A simple HSV threshold might do. Now, it's going to be difficult to recognize/classify those labels because the characters aren't even oriented properly.

Comment: Why don't you use colored dots to encode each piece and detect that instead? Something like Pawns -> label with a green, big, nice dot. Bishops -> red dot, Knights -> blue dot, etc.

Comment: @fana well, I don't have a better/other chessboard so that's what I'm trying to work with.

Comment: @stateMachine the distorted image is given just like that by the web camera I'm using, reason why I was contemplating using my cellphone instead. Thanks for the tip, agree working with colored dots would be easier than letters, if I remember correctly opencv can give coordinates of contours so if I can get them from the colors dots instead that would do, I'm gonna try that later, right now I'm working on the rest of the assignment. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, this worked, after this it's simple to find the square the colors are in with `c2v.findContours`, `cv2.contourArea()` and `cv2.moments()`.

```
corners = find_chessboard(frame)
corners = sorted(corners, key=lambda k: [k[1], k[0]])
corners2 = []
for i in range(10):
    corners2 = corners2 + sorted(corners[i*9:(i+1)*9], key=lambda k: [k[0]])
```